# IE crashes with no error msg while posting text with Ajax

Tags: internet-explorer-8

As the title is self explanatory, I have a html textarea and a HTML input type="button". Simply I call an asmx web service (via ScriptManager, ms ajax fw). I call the service to send the text and save to DB. After calling this service a few times, IE (8) crashes with no error msg whatsoever. Any leads will be appreciated.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

We have come across what sounds like a similar issue.
IE would crash after calling and AJAX method (we used jquery's ajax).

On successfully returning from the web method, the javascript replace the innerhtml of an element with what was returned.

The cause of the crash was due to a self closing label element in the original html when some dynamic value was null:

```
   <label id="sometext" />
```

IE 8 does not seem to process this self closing element properly. When the on success method tries to replace the innerHTML the DOM was not correct and IE crashed.

To correct the issue we now force a space into the label in case a null was returned:

```
   <label id="sometext">&nbsp;</label>
```

Firefox, chrome and other versions of IE seem to handle the self closing tag correctly.